# Jsp login with messages from servlet and a valid url

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

I want wo make a login form that displays error messages (like "Wrong user/password - try again").

**LoginHandler.java:**

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginHandler extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //...
    if (userInvalid()) {
      request.setAttribute("error", "Wrong user/password - try again");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

**index.jsp:**

```
<p><% out.println(request.getAttribute("error")); %></p>
<form action="/login" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
```

Everything works fine, but I dont like the URL http://< server >:8080/login I got after the `request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);` dispatches the request. It's not a URL that can be dispayed in my setup in a browser when you enter it.

Is there a way you can send the error message to the index.jsp whitout using session variables and with a URL like this http://< server >:8080/index.jsp ?

Comment: No, not with JSP, but you can use JavaScript, have a look at AJAX

Comment: try agian ->  try again

Comment: Why did I get two downvotes? Is the question to trivial? A duplicate? Please clearify so I can improve the question and learn for the future.

Comment: @BalusC: Your recomended example has the same problem as I have.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble. But your comment has no hint to the problem and I really appreciate an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you get in the browser the address of the servlet. If you then navigate to this address you get an error? If this is the case, you could "redispatch" in the doGet-Method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

In this case, the servlet should forward to the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `response.sendRedirect` instead of forward to display the correct url. Here is the sample code. This may not be a good approach but you can use this.

*In servlet*

```
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    resp.sendRedirect("login.jsp?errorMsg=Ivalid usernam or password");
    }
```

*In login.jsp*

```
   <%= request.getParameter("errorMsg") %>
```